# System.loadLibrary() gives error on loading on a suse machine

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

I am writing a Java app on linux (SuSE) that should communicates with a native library using JNI. The native library has been build using the Android NDK.

The lib has been creating using the command `ndk-build`.
The `Android.mk` looks like this:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := hello-jni
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hello-jni.c

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

The `Application.mk` is like this

```
APP_ABI := x86
APP_STL := system
```

The `.so` is being build for the x86 environment.

On loading this library through `System.loadLibrary()`, it gives the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError.
libhello-jni.so: libstdc++.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Tried many things including setting `APP_STL`. But the error is not Resolved.

I am using `ndk-build` because, finally the whole thing has to be moved to Android which requires that the lib is created using ndk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use the NDK to build libraries for use on a normal Linux, for a number of reasons, including that the C libraries and their associated dynamic linker are different and the library naming conventions differ.  Typically you would also have a different processor (though the NDK now supports most that might be in your development machine), and perhaps a subtly different ABI even when the processor matches.

You can still accomplish your goal of testing your jni code on the desktop, you will just need to build it with a toolchain targeting your desktop Linux environment (with appropriate settings for jni usage there), then re-build it with the NDK for your android target.

Answer (score 0):

As per ur Module name LOCAL_MODULE    := hello-jni, You should use

System.loadLibrary("hello-jni");

Comment: No, this is not the problem - libhello-jni.so *is* the file name implied by calling loadLibrary("hello-jni"). The unsatisfied link error is for the C++ library required by the jni library, not for the jni library itself. And the reason it is unsatisfied is that the library is not compatible with the platform it is trying to run on.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I am able to build the lib (using gcc), load it and invoke the CPP interface api from java (from command line using  - java myMainClass ) 
  But when I run the same java source from the eclipse IDE (from ADT), it gives the error:
"
        Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:          myMainClass.printLine()Ljava/lang/String;
    at myMainClass.printLine(Native Method)
    at myMainClass.main(myMainClass.java:26)
"
I have set the lib path in the IDE as follows:
Properties->Java Build Path-> Source tab ->Native library location

The java source is as follows:

```
   import java.lang.System;
    import java.lang.String;


    public class myMainClass {


        // native functions
        public native String printLine();
        /**
         * @param args
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                System.out.println("Hello world! in java");
                myMainClass m = new myMainClass();
                String s1 = m.printLine();

                System.out.println(s1);

        }

        static {
        System.loadLibrary("hello");
               }
    }
```

CPP source is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "myMainClass.h"

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_myMainClass_printLine
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject object)
{
        return env->NewStringUTF("Hello from JNI !");
}
```

Comment: Do not use the answer form to post follow-up questions.  Since this is no longer an Android issue, and substantially different from what you originally asked, you should post this as it's own new question rather than as an edit to your current one.